# Динамическое изменение поля класса

Tags: python, ооп

Имею код исходный код:

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self):
    self.hp = 20
    self.mp = 5
...
  def magic(self, other, target, attribute, random_number):
```

Методу/подпрограмме *magic* передаются: константы *self*, *other* - экземпляры класса *Player* и переменные *target*, *attribute*, *random_number*. Например,

```
# В данном примере происходит попытка изменения значения поля hp объекта player_2 на 10
player_1.magic(player_2, "other", "hp", 10)
```

Необходимо, чтобы *attribute* нужного *target* заменился на *random_number*. Было предпринята попытка решить задачу следующим способом:

```
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.player_attributes = {'hp': self.hp,
                              'mp': self.mp,
    }
...
  def magic(self, other, target, attribute, random_number):
    target_dict = {'self': self,
                   'other': other
    }
    target_dict[target].player_attributes[attribute] = random_number
```

Код не сработал, как ожидалось: вместо изменения *self.hp* или *self.mp* меняются значения словаря *player_attributes*. Конечно, можно сделать простую проверку *attribute* на соответствие словам "hp" и "mp", но это выглядит неэффективным, так как полей у класса в последствие будет больше, чем два.

Указателей в Питоне нет, знаю, тогда как можно решить данную проблему, кроме банальной проверки передаваемого *attribute*?

Comment: Разве не так должно быть `player_1.magic(player_2, "other", "hp", 10)`? И в `init` у вас не `self.player_attributes = ` должно быть?

Comment: @gil9red Ах да, когда копировал код и изменял его для создания этого вопроса, забыл исправить некоторые вещи. На самом деле и _other_ и _hp_ - переменные, содержащие строки. А _self_ там было, я его не скопировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле этот код меняет только значение словаря, а сам атрибут останется как и был:

```
target_dict[target].player_attributes[attribute] = random_number
```

Я бы воспользовался методом [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) чтобы проверить, что запрашиваемый атрибут есть у объекта и метод [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) чтобы рефлексивно установить значение атрибута, пример:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 20
        self.mp = 5

    def magic(self, other: 'Player', target: str, attribute: str, random_number):
        target_dict = {
            'self': self,
            'other': other
        }
        target_obj = target_dict[target]
        if not hasattr(target_obj, attribute):
            print('Object {} does not have the "{}" attribute'.format(target_obj, attribute))
            return

        setattr(target_obj, attribute, random_number)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Player(hp={self.hp} mp={self.mp})'.format(self=self)


player_1 = Player()
player_2 = Player()
print(player_1, player_2)
# Player(hp=20 mp=5) Player(hp=20 mp=5)

player_1.magic(player_2, "other", "hp", 10)
print(player_1, player_2)
# Player(hp=20 mp=5) Player(hp=10 mp=5)
```

Comment: Ух ты, большое спасибо! Даже не знал о таком методе.

Comment: @SergeyNaN, обратите внимание, что я добавил проверку на наличие атрибута через hasattr

Comment: Обратил, благодарю! Впрочем, первый попавшийся сайт тоже подсунул эту функцию "на закуску".

Answer (score 0):

Судя по этому методу `def magic(self, other, target, attribute, random_number)` -
`target` это выбор между `(self и other)`, в котором потом произойдет `ob.attribute=random_number`.
И этот выбор(target) должен быть сделан До запуска метода, так какой смысл в передаче всех этих переменных `(self, other, target)`, если можно сделать не с 5 аргументами, а с 3:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 20
        self.mp = 5

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Player(hp={self.hp} mp={self.mp})'.format(self=self)


def magic(target_obj: 'Player', attribute: str, random_number):
    if hasattr(target_obj, attribute):
        setattr(target_obj, attribute, random_number)
    else:
        raise AttributeError('Object {} does not have the "{}" attribute'.format(target_obj, attribute))


player_1 = Player()
player_2 = Player()
magic(player_1, "hp", 10)
magic(player_2, "mp", 10)
```

или так:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 20
        self.mp = 5

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Player(hp={self.hp} mp={self.mp})'.format(self=self)

    def magic(self, attribute: str, random_number):
        if hasattr(self, attribute):
            setattr(self, attribute, random_number)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Object {} does not have the "{}" attribute'.format(self, attribute))


player_1 = Player()
player_2 = Player()
Player.magic(player_1, "hp", 10)
Player.magic(player_2, "mp", 10)
```